# Highcharts разные цвета для линии графика

Tags: highcharts

Есть ли способ в js библиотеке Highcharts установить разные цвета для одного графика? Чтобы линия с отрицательным значением была одного цвета, а та же линия с положительным значением - другого?

**UPD**

Вот так строю сам график

```
new Highcharts.Chart({
    "chart":{
        "renderTo":"chart1",
        "height":200,
        "width":300
    },
    "xAxis":{
        "type":"datetime",
        "title":false,
        "dateTimeLabelFormats":{"day":"%e.%m"}
    },
    "series":[{
        "data":[{
            "x":1515184552000,"y":3.62,"color":"#ff0000", 
            ...
        }],
    }],
    "tooltip":{"enabled":false},
    "legend":{"enabled":false}
});
```

Получается вот такой график

[image: График]

Нужно чтобы линия ниже нуля была другим цветом. Как видно из кода, пробую в массив `data` передавать `color`, но при этом меняется только цвет точки при наведении на график, а не сама линия графика.

Comment: приложите ваш [mcve] с графиком да хотя бы не попытками вашими, а хотя бы одного цвета, скрин - что хотите получить например

Comment: обновил вопрос..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ, наверное, уже не актуален, но тем не менее.

Используйте свойство [`negativeColor`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.negativeColor) серии

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    series: [ {
        name: 'test',
        data: [-1, 1, 2, -1, -2, 0, 1, 1],
        color: "red",
        negativeColor: "blue",
    }, ],
});
```

```css
#container {
 min-width: 310px;
 max-width: 800px;
 height: 200px;
 margin: 0 auto
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```